# UDS protocol timeout for negative response when suppress positive response is set for a frame request

Tags: timeout, can-bus, suppress

What is the timeout one should wait to make sure a negative response is not received when a suppress positive bit is set for a frame request?

Answer (score 3):

The minimum timeout value to wait for the client when *suppressPosRspMsgIndicationBit* is set to *TRUE* is [image: P3 CAN_Physical] in case of physically addressed server and [image: P3 CAN_Functional] for functionally addressed servers.

For physical addressing this value will be equal [image: P2 CAN_Server_max].

References: [ISO 15765-3:2004](https://www.iso.org/standard/33618.html) at section *6.3.5.3 Minimum time between client request messages*; [ISO 14229-2:2013](https://www.iso.org/standard/45763.html) at section *8.3 Minimum time between client request messages*